# How to run a scheduled task to stop and start SSRS service with elevated permissions?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I have this SSRS latency issues on my site. So I have googled it and found out that it is the common issues for so many people. Here it is:

1. I have created a powershell script as follows:

   ```
   Stop-Service "SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)"
   Start-Service "SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)"
   $wc = New-Object system.net.webClient
   $cred = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
   $wc.Credentials = $cred
   $src = $wc.DownloadString("http://example.com/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx")
   ```
2. When i run this script from poweshell cmd it is throwing me an error says cannot open/access sql report server service. It seems like permissions issue. Then I came with this online solution, which invokes/elevates admin permissions to run the script to that perticular user.

   ```
   function Invoke-Admin() {

       param ( [string]$program = $(throw "Please specify a program" ),
           [string]$argumentString = "",
           [switch]$waitForExit )

       $psi = new-object "Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo"
       $psi.FileName = $program 
       $psi.Arguments = $argumentString
       $psi.Verb = "runas"
       $proc = [Diagnostics.Process]::Start($psi)
       if ( $waitForExit ) {
           $proc.WaitForExit();
       }
   }
   ```

But I dont know how to run this function before running that script. Please suggest. I have added this function also to the same script file and added function-Admin() call at the top of the script to to execute this function before running the script as follows:

```
function-Admin()
 Stop-Service "SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)"
    Start-Service "SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)"
    $wc = New-Object system.net.webClient
    $cred = [System.Net.CredentialCache]::DefaultNetworkCredentials
    $wc.Credentials = $cred
    $src = $wc.DownloadString("http://example.com/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx")
```

But is throwing following error:

```
Please specify a program
At C:\SSRS_Script\SSRSScript.ps1:3 char:39
+     param ( [string]$program = $(throw <<<<  "Please specify a program" ),
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Please specify a program:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Please specify a program
```

Comment: Invoke-Admin() is supposed to be called with parameter not simply called in the beginning of a script. Ex: Invoke-Admin("SSRSScript.ps1") would call your script and, in theory, run it will elevated rights. In your case i would convert Invoke-Admin() into a standalone script that would call `SSRSScript.ps1`. I am assuming that should work.

Comment: You meant to create separate script file just for Invoke-admin function and how to or where to call this SSRSScript.ps1 file?

Comment: In case someone reads my first comment my assumption was incorrect. If you try to run `Invoke-Admin` to call a script as part of an argument to powershell.exe. `-program "Powershell.exe" -argumentString "-file C:\SSRS_Script\SSRSScript.ps1"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting that error because the function `Invoke-Admin()` was designed to have parameters passed for the program you wanted to run with elevated privledges. If you want your powershell script `SSRSScript.ps1` to use this `Invoke-Admin()` you could convert it to a standalone script.

Take the code without the function declartion and outer brackets. Save this a file called `Invoke-Admin.ps1`

```
param ( [string]$program = $(throw "Please specify a program" ),
    [string]$argumentString = "",
    [switch]$waitForExit )

$psi = new-object "Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo"
$psi.FileName = $program 
$psi.Arguments = $argumentString
$psi.Verb = "runas"
$proc = [Diagnostics.Process]::Start($psi)
if ( $waitForExit ) {
    $proc.WaitForExit();
}
```

With that created then you could try to elevate your script with the following:

```
C:\*pathtoscript*\Invoke-Admin.ps1 -program "Powershell.exe" -argumentString "-file C:\SSRS_Script\SSRSScript.ps1"
```

You should get the elevation prompt at that point and then, once accepted, will run another window with your script using admin rights.

This is by no means the only way to accomplish this goal.

**Scheduler**

You have this in the title but dont really cover it in the question. Running this as a scheduled task will not work since it requires user input. You could however just make a task with your script as is assuming it works unattended.

General Tab

```
Run whether user is logged on or not
Run with highest privileges
```

Action > New...

```
Action: Start a program Program/script: %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe 
Add arguments: -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -NoProfile -File C:\SSRS_Script\SSRSScript.ps1
Start in (optional): %SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
```